# running into "unknown tablefield" but it is defined

Tags: mysql, sql

running a query and converting the stored unix-time-stamp to the certain date-format. this i wanna compare with the timestamp of today...

i am running within the where condition into the error that "D" is not known?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct db_suid), 
    date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%H') AS H,
    date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%Y-%m-%d') AS D
FROM air_vault 
WHERE CURRENT_DATE = D
GROUP BY H
```

at the end i wanna get the distinct number of values per hour of today

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias defined in select also in where  clause

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct db_suid), 
    date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%H') AS H,
    date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%Y-%m-%d') AS D
FROM air_vault 
WHERE CURRENT_DATE = date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY H
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct db_suid), 
       date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%H') AS H,
       date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%Y-%m-%d') AS D
FROM air_vault av
WHERE d_utime >= unix_timestamp(curdate()) and
      d_utime < unix_timetamp(curdate() + interval 1 day)
GROUP BY H, D;
```

Why is the logic phrased this way?  The conditions in the `where` clause can use an index on `d_utime` if it is available -- or partitions if the data is partitioned on that column.  That can significantly increase the performance of the query.

When a column is the argument to a function (such as `from_unixtime()`), indexes are almost never used.

Answer (score 0):

manged my issue by modifying my WHERE condition:

WHERE CURRENT_DATE = date_format(from_unixtime(d_utime),'%Y-%m-%d')